# Qt widget and Software Input Panel must both remain on top

Tags: c++, qt

I've got a Qt dialog window that contains a `QPlainTextEdit` widget, for which I've created a Software Input Panel (SIP), following the example [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tools-inputpanel.html). The function of the dialog window requires it to remain on top. As such, the SIP too must remain on top -- but overlaying the dialog. The problem I find is that:

1. If I set `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` on the dialog only the SIP falls behind it.
2. If I set `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` on the SIP only the dialog window that can now be eclipsed by other windows, same thing happens if I set `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` on the dialog *and* SIP, clearly `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` is applicable to one widget only.

What can be done to ensure that the dialogs stack in this order? Making the SIP modal is not really an option or good solution.

If it matters I'm coding in C++

**PS**
Please take a look at my follow on [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432707/raising-a-qt-qeventwindowactivate-event) as well.

Comment: Does the SIP have a parent? Is the dialog modal? Which OS and desktop environment are you using?

Comment: OS, Windows 7. The other questions were answerd in my post. The SIP is not modal, and is created by and `InputPanelContext` object as shown in the example.

Comment: I meant the other dialog, not the SIP. I don't see where you mention parenting (important as that affects the stacking order).

Comment: The parent dialog is the main window.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is that the MyInputPanel QWidget is being constructed with Qt::Tool flag. The purpose of that flag is to ensure that a window ALWAYS appears on top of any other windows which is not what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, without `Qt::Tool` the SIP appears underneath the `QPlainTextWidget` dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround. I set `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` on the SIP and main dialog, but move the SIP just below the main dialog, so that the SIP is not occluded by it.